# Python ImportError: No module name parse

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling, module, importerror

I keep getting this same error and I have tried everything I know how to fix it. The error I am getting is this: `ImportError: No module name parse` Does anyone know how to fix this? I am currently running python 2.7.12. Also here is my code:

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import http.client, urllib.parse, json


# **********************************************
# *** Update or verify the following values. ***
# **********************************************

# Replace the subscriptionKey string value with your valid subscription key.
subscriptionKey =  "My_Access_Key"

# Verify the endpoint URI.  At this writing, only one endpoint is used for Bing
# search APIs.  In the future, regional endpoints may be available.  If you
# encounter unexpected authorization errors, double-check this value against
# the endpoint for your Bing Web search instance in your Azure dashboard.
host = "api.cognitive.microsoft.com"
path = "/bing/v7.0/search"

term = "Microsoft Cognitive Services"

def BingWebSearch(search):
    "Performs a Bing Web search and returns the results."

    headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscriptionKey}
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(host)
    query = urllib.parse.quote(search)
    conn.request("GET", path + "?q=" + query, headers=headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    headers = [k + ": " + v for (k, v) in response.getheaders()
                   if k.startswith("BingAPIs-") or k.startswith("X-MSEdge-")]
    return headers, response.read().decode("utf8")

if len(subscriptionKey) == 32:

    print('Searching the Web for: ', term)

    headers, result = BingWebSearch(term)
    print("\nRelevant HTTP Headers:\n")
    print("\n".join(headers))
    print("\nJSON Response:\n")
    print(json.dumps(json.loads(result), indent=4))

else:

    print("Invalid Bing Search API subscription key!")
    print("Please paste yours into the source code.")
```

Comment: how can I write it in Python 2?

Comment: Also, I have tried upgrading to python 3 but my machine still recognizes python2, idk how.

Comment: Look in the [version 2.7 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/index.html) to refactor your code.

Comment: @Alias311 type `python3 script.py` instead of `python script.py` in your terminal

Comment: @FHTMitchell Dude you just fixed it thanks!  Idk why I didn't try that before!

Answer (score 0):

Like [snakecharmerb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5320906/snakecharmerb) told you, urllib.parse is from Python3.

I think you should use [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#module-urlparse) as the `urllib.parse` and [httplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html?highlight=http#module-httplib) as the `http` module.

If you have installed Python3 in your machine (from apt or similar) maybe it doesn't changed your `/usr/bin/python` link to the newer version, but I'm pretty sure you should have a `python3` or `python3.x` command installed.

If you want to substitute the `python` command with the `python3.x` you have to create a symbolic link to you `/usr/bin` folder. You can do it with:

`sudo rm /usr/bin/python
sudo ln -s <path_to_your_python3_bin> /usr/bin/python`

Maybe the rm is not necessary, but it doesn't hurt.